# WP_Query on different post_types with additional conditions per post_type

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

in short I have the following situation: products that are posted by the users which have a custom post type. Call them "ads". Ads have a 1-1 link to WooCommerce Products.
Next to that I have WooCommerce Products that are Vendor Item (they are added by a multiple vendor plugin) and distinguish from other post_type products with their meta_key "_vendor_product" set to 1.

So far I made 2 queries and added them:

```
$ads = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'ads',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'product_id',
                'value' => $product_ids,
                'compare' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    )
);
$shop_items = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post__in' => $product_ids,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_vendor_product',
                'value' => 1,
                'compare' => '='
            )
        )
    )
 );
}

// Include shop items in the stream of products
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array('paged' => $paged));
$wp_query->posts = array_merge( $ads->posts, $shop_items->posts );
$wp_query->post_count = $ads->post_count + $shop_items->post_count;
```

But I need them both in one WP_Query, as otherwise somehwere my actions/filters/pagination seem to break.
I know I can query different post_types by `'post_type' => array( 'ads', 'product' )` but the condition of `_vendor_product = 1` only applies to the items of post_type `product` and not to `ads`.

What I need is basically

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta 
WHERE (post_type = 'ads') 
OR 
(post_type = 'product' AND meta_key = '_vendor_product' AND meta_value = 1) 
AND 
wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
```

Is it possible to achieve this within the boundaries of WP_Query?

Comment: Please see if this works for your situation i.e. in your combined query you add relation OR http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191748/how-can-i-apply-a-meta-query-for-a-single-custom-post-type-in-the-main-query

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, that won't work, because that way I would still have all "product" posts that are not created by a vendor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that you can achieve it within one query directly (however somebody may bring up a solution). However I suggest an easy workaround to this problem - find out the post IDs and make a single query from that:

```
global $wpdb;

$all_needed = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT wp_posts.id FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta 
WHERE (post_type = 'ads') 
OR 
(post_type = 'product' AND meta_key = '_vendor_product' AND meta_value = 1) 
AND 
wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id');

// extract_ids is a pseudo-code function - check what the result actually is and make an array of post_ids
$post_ids = extract_ids($all_needed)

// now you have your single query
$query = new WP_Query(array('post__in'=>$post_ids));

// proceed ....
```

Comment: While this solution works, pagination is a mess. You do not know what data to take since you do not know how many of each where on the previous page.

Comment: However you can solve pagination in some ways.
a) SQL LIMIT
b) If not too much posts, get all and count
c) Use usort in PHP or SQL sorting possibilities

Answer (score 1):

I achieved my result basically the same way Blackbam suggested, although without directly involving SQL.

If anyone ever finds this I will post my solution as it gave me a bit of a headache to figure out why my results were limited to 10 when using get_posts on WP_Query (the solution was `'nopaging'` in WP_Query.

```
$ps_ads = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'ads',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'nopaging' => true,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    )
);
$shop_items = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'nopaging' => true,
        'post__in' => $product_ids,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_vendor_product',
                'value' => 1,
                'compare' => '='
            )
        )
    )
 );
}

// Sum up all IDs

$ad_ids = $ps_ads->get_posts();
$shop_items_ids = $shop_items->get_posts();
$ids = array_merge($ad_ids, $shop_items_ids);

$wp_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => array( 'ads' , 'product' ),
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post__in' => $ids
    )
);
```

Hope it helps.